# "Зазмеился"

Tags: словообразование

Подскажите, можно ли употребить подобное слово? Мне кажется, что оно вполне обосновано и применимо в значении: "начал двигаться по траектории синусоиды" (описал криво, но, думаю, доступно). Скажем, во время сильного дождя потоки воды могут зазмеиться по земле. Как вы считаете?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Из словаря:

ЗМЕИТЬСЯ, змеится; нсв. 1. Тянуться извилистой линией; виться, извиваться. Ручей змеится между камней. Дорожка змеится по холмам. 2. Блуждать, скользить (обычно об улыбке). В уголках губ змеилась насмешливая улыбка.

В Нацкорпусе отмечается употребление слова "зазмеиться", где приставка ЗА имеет значение начала действия, например: "Вдруг зазмеился яркий громовой удар в промежутке между тучею и морем". "Снова зазмеился между обвалами путь".

Comment: Благодарю.